# How to detect similar URLs but dut diffrent languages in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, string-comparison

I'm trying to detect similar URLs from an Array of URLs.
I need to compare set different URLs and to test if they are originally the same URLs or not?
As for an example I'm expecting that [example.com/en/open](http://example.com/en/open) should be detected similar to [example.com/es/open](http://example.com/es/open) and similar to [example.com/open](http://example.com/en/open). Another example for a website like booking.com I'm expecting that https://www.booking.com/index.ar.htm should be detected  similar to  https://www.booking.com/index.en.htm

Any Ideas!

Comment: I don't think this is something that should be left to JavaScript. You can try to compare the last part of the string and see if it match but that won't help you if the keywords in the URL are translated to the other language. I think using a server-side solution and checking the `link` tag for a canonical URL combined with the language attribute on the HTML tag would be the best.

Comment: mmm, what if the website is not implementing canonical links at all?

Comment: Then you are left to strings comparison which again will be useless if the URL itself is translated. Most of the websites that care about SEO implement canonical URLs (check booking.com it's there). Also it is generated automatically from popular CMSs like WP.

Comment: Let's assume that strings comparison is the best solution then do you know a generic regex to do it for me!

Comment: Most of the websites now use the language as a part of the URL (like /en/ or /fr/ ... etc). You can use `split` the string over the `/` and get the last item and compare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two language code schemes you're looking for are identified by the sample URLs you show:

```
https://www.booking.com/index.en.htm
https://www.booking.com/index.ar.htm
```

and

```
http://example.com/en/open
http://example.com/es/open
```

and

```
http://example.com/en
http://example.com/es
```

Then, you can design a regex that will replace any two letter language code between a delimiters of a slash or period with a canonical set of characters that is unlikely to naturally occur in the URL.  That will essentially neutralize the language code and you can then compare the remaining URLs:

FYI, there's a list of language codes here: https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

```
function removeLanguageIdentifier(url) {
    let re = /([\/\.])(aa|ab|af|ad|sq|am|ar|an|hy|as|av|ae|ay|az|ba|bm|eu|be|bn|bh|bi|bo|bs|br|bg|my|ca|cs|ch|ce|zh|cu|cv|kw|co|cr|cy|cs|da|de|dv|nl|dz|el|en|eo|et|eu|ee|fo|fa|fj|fi|fr|fy|ff|ka|gd|fa|dl|gv|el|gn|gu|ht|ja|he|hz|hi|ho|hr|hu|hy|ig|is|io|ii|iu|ie|ia|id|ik|is|it|jv|ja|kl|kn|ks|ka|kr|kk|km|ki|rw|ky|kv|kg|ko|kj|ku|lo|la|lv|li|ln|lt|lb|lu|lg|mk|mh|ml|mi|mr|ms|mk|mg|mt|mn|mi|ms|my|na|nv|nr|nd|ng|ne|nl|nn|nb|no|ny|oc|oj|or|om|os|pa|fa|pi|pl|pt|ps|qu|rm|ro|rn|sg|sa|si|sk|sl|se|sm|sn|sd|so|st|es|sq|sc|sr|ss|su|sw|sv|ty|ta|tt|te|tg|tl|th|bo|ti|to|tn|ts|tk|tf|tw|ug|uk|ur|uz|ve|vi|vo|cy|wa|wo|xh|yi|yo|za|zh|zu])([\/\.$])/i;
    return url.replace(re, "$1_._$3");
}
```

If you then just call `removeLanguageIdentifier(url)` on each of two URLs you want to compare and compare the result of that function for each, then you will neutralize any two letter country between the two delimiters you show.

Note: This isn't foolproof.  If someone has a regular URL with a two letter country code as a path segment all by itself that is not intended to be a language code, then there is now way for you to know one way or the other if it is supposed to be interpreted as a language code unless you have prior knowledge of how that specific domain encodes their URLs and can build that smarts into your function.

So, the best we can do with the limited information you've provided is make an educated "guess" on what looks like it might be a language code of the three forms you've provided.

Comment: @HazemHagrass - Like I said "this covers the examples you show".  If you have more examples you want to cover, then you have to disclose those and figure out how to modify the code to include them.  I've added support for that one by adding a `$` to the last group.